# Стилистика: оформление или элементы оформления

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика

Например:
Знаки препинания — это оформление логики.
Знаки препинания — это элементы оформления логики.

Фонари — это оформление площади.
Фонари — это элементы оформления площади.

Как правильно?

Answer (score 3):

Если использовать вариант без слова "элемент", получится, что фонари являются единственным оформлением площади, а знаки препинания, соответственно - логики.

Лучше написать:

> Знаки препинания — ***это один из элементов*** оформления логики.
>
> Фонари — ***это один из элементов*** оформления площади.

Answer (score 3):

ОФОРМЛЕНИЕ 1. к Оформить и Оформиться (название действия). Художник по оформлению витрин. О. документов. О. на работу. 2. **Внешний вид, форма чего-л.** О. книг, спектакля. Радоваться праздничному оформлению улиц. Подарить альбом с нарядным оформлением.

Соответственно, фонари - это не внешний вид или форма площади, а именно **элементы**, образующие внешний вид площади.

Answer (score 2):

Элемент — это составляющая часть чего-либо. Элементом оформления фонари могут быть, по моему скромному мнению. На площади ведь, помимо фонарей, есть другие элементы оформления. А вот предложение «Фонари — это оформление площади» мне кажется неправильным, однако здесь я особо ничего сказать не могу.

Answer (score 1):

Если кому-то захотелось так определить роль знаков препинания — «элементы оформления логики», то пусть так и будет. Частное мнение. Фонари могут быть украшением и элементами оформления (иллюминации) площади, как и другие прочие, декоративные, но в первую очередь по своей функции они — элементы благоустройства: освещения.